# Why Don't Electrons "Try" to Flow in an Open Circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits

I understand that electrons can't cross an open switch, but why don't they at least move towards the open switch when a battery is connected? Doesn't the voltage cause motion towards the positive terminal?

Comment: They do try to flow through an open circuit just usually they don't have in enough "umph" to get through the gap. They can do so if the potential difference between the electrodes is high enough. Through dry air it is about 25kV/m = 25V/mm, less for damp air; through vacuum it depends on the metal, etc.

Comment: I see, thank you! Does that mean that current can flow through the wire until it reaches the open switch?

Comment: if by "current" you mean the average motion of charges induced by the battery chemistry then when the gap voltage is not high enough, whatever high means in a particular situation, yes, that motion representing the current will end by charges accumulating on the electrode. That charge separation is the cause of the open circuit voltage or unloaded voltage of the battery that a good voltmeter having very high internal resistance will measure.

Comment: Yes, there is some current flow. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AXv49dDQJw) by AlphaPhoenix provides an excellent demonstration! I strongly encourage you to watch it, as it addresses exactly the question you are asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An open switch can be thought of as a capacitor with a very small capacitance with air as the dielectric.  As such opposite sign charges can reside on the two sides of a switch wand there will be a potential difference across the switch. Thus there will be a time when current flows along the wires until the capacitor (switch) is fully charged, i.e., the potential difference across the switch is equal to that across the terminals of the voltage source. 
As air is not a perfect insulator, a minute current can flow across the switch contacts and if the potential difference across the switch contacts is large enough so that the electric field between the contacts exceeds 30 kV/cm, the air will break down (become a conductor) and a significant current will flow through the air gap. 
Even with low voltages arcing can occur as switches are opened and closed as the air breaks down and the can cause radio interference.  At high voltages the effect can be quite spectacular particularly at night as the video *[High Voltage 345,000 volt switch closing at night!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnhob9zqY3w)* shows. In the video the switch is being closed and when the air gap is small enough the electric field between the switch contacts is large enough for the air to breakdown and a significant current pass through it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! This leads me to a follow-up question: If a light bulb is placed before an open switch in a series circuit, and then I connect the battery as the final step, could the light bulb flash briefly (with the switch still open)? My understanding is that the bulb would emit light until the voltage across the switch matches the voltage across the battery terminals.

Comment: @KonradKawka, no.   The amount of charge flow/power is tiny.   You could measure it with the right equipment, but it's not enough to warm up a lightbulb.   The bulb would conduct charge until the voltage equalized.  But it would not produce light.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I have seen a LED bulb being slightly lit when the switch was off because the switch was on the neutral and not the hot wire (old house).

Comment: This is giving me flashbacks of [the infamous Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY).

Answer (score 3):

If instead of a switch, you consider a capacitor, then when a capacitor is being charged by say a battery, the negative terminal of the battery moves electrons onto one plate of the capacitor while the positive battery terminal  removes the same number of electrons from of the other plate of the capacitor,  while electrons never move through the gap between the plates (like a switch).

This movement of electrons (current) to and from the capacitor plates constitutes current even though the electrons don't physically move from one plate of the capacitor to the other plate through the space between the plates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! I think my confusion stemmed from a book diagram that used colored wires to illustrate current flow. I mistakenly expected this coloring to continue up to the open switch to represent the electron buildup. However, I now understand that the uncolored section aligns with how conventional current diagrams depict open circuits. While I also briefly mixed up the direction of conventional flow (positive to negative), that was a separate point of confusion.

Comment: The coloring does not represent the current up to the switch. It represents the voltage right up to the switch